# Unable to mock JdbcTemplate in testing spring boot service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

In the test case for service,I am unable to resolve dependency of dao class and JdbcTemplate.

```
public class TestPromotionUsingJunit {

    @InjectMocks
    private ItemService itemService;

    @Mock
    private ItemDAOImpl itemDAOImpl;
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        itemService = new ItemService();

    }

    @Test
    public void testFindMax() {
        Product pro1 = new Product();
        pro1.setPluCode("4900692627408");
        pro1.setCategoryNo("2");
        pro1.setCategoryName("Women");
        pro1.setProductName("T-Shirt10163");
        pro1.setColor("CY");
        pro1.setSize("32");
        BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(94.00);
        BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(8);
        pro1.setPrice(b1);
        pro1.setTax(b2);
        Product pro2 = new Product();
        pro2.setPluCode("4900692627408");

        assertEquals(pro1.getPrice(), itemService.getItem(pro1));

    }

}
```

Here ItemService should return product object but it returns null. Due to internally unable to solve dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@InjectMocks creates a mock instance of itemService, but then

```
itemService = new ItemService();
```

creates a real instance and throws the mock away.  In setupMock(), after itemService is constructed, try adding the equivalent of this:

```
itemService.setItemDao(itemDAOImpl);
```

So you'll have a real ItemService which uses a mock DAO.

Then in testFindMax() configure the DAO to return pro1, something like this:

```
when(itemDAOImpl.getItem(...)).thenReturn(pro1);
```